# What are "set buttons"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Virtual thumbsticks on both sides of the screen control movement and viewing, while **set buttons** cover the standard FPS controls (shooting, reloading, switching weapons, etc).

Source: http://toucharcade.com/2014/09/03/bioshock-review/

Are they buttons which you can put (set) anywhere on the screen? Or maybe buttons which are grouped (in a set) in some way? Or are they something else?

Comment: What, for that matter, is "brining a new generation of gamers"? Lesson: be careful learning English from texts that nobody proofreads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this context, I think "set" means more like *established, fixed*, or *unchangeable*. 
Their functions are already "set" (as in stone) and cannot be customized.